# why won't this program give me the output i want?

Tags: c, printf

I've written this simple code so I can see what's wrong with a more complex program that I have written.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n = 0, i = 1, a = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    while (i <= n)
    {
        scanf(" %d", &a);
        printf("%d", &a);
        i++;
    }
}
```

but when I run the program it goes like this:
4
1
6487620
what's wrong with it?

Comment: Nothing's wrong, it's doing what it is asked to do. you're invoking UB, BTW.

Answer (score 1):

In your code

```
 printf("%d", &a);
```

should be

```
printf("%d", a); // don;t print address....
```

FWIW, passing an address (a pointer type) as an argument to `%d` is a mismatch and invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: I fixed that, but now when i want to run the program this happens:

Comment: C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file a.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @ShabnamSheikhha This means that your compilation failed.

Answer (score 1):

When you use 
 `printf("%d", &a);`

this means that it will print the address of `a`

and to print the value of `a` you have to wright

`printf("%d", a);`

and after making the changes compile the program and try to rerun :)

Answer (score 0):

You pass the address of `a` instead of its value to `printf`.  You should also output a linefeed to separate the numbers:

```
printf("%d\n", a);
```